# What is "spin-orbit torque?"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin, spin-orbit

I am trying really hard to understand the concept of spin-orbit torque. It is a new-ish discovery in the field of spintronics and has many applications for magnetic devices. The information that has been published on it thus far is too advanced for me, although I have tried to understand it.

Here are some things that I have been told and am trying to piece together:

1. Spin-orbit torques arise from the spin hall effect creating a spin-current, which then provides a spin-transfer torque that acts on the magnetization of a ferromagnet. Something that arises from this interaction is called a spin-orbit torque.
2. I know that it is not the same thing as spin-transfer torque.
3. It has also been called a "spin-orbit field," and that a "spin hall field" would have been a more appropriate name, because it does create an "effective" field. The name is confusing because there is debate about what causes it (either the spin hall effect, the Rashba effect, or both).
4. I know that the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation is relevant. I believe one of the terms may be referred to as "spin-orbit torque."

Here is a (lengthy) review paper on the topic:
http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/roypta/369/1948/3175.full.pdf

I am an undergraduate, so I would appreciate answers that are not overly complicated. I am merely looking for a conceptual understanding of what this means.

Comment: For future reference in the abstract the explanation "spin–orbit (SO) torque, is produced by the flow of an electric current in a crystalline structure lacking inversion symmetry, which transfers orbital angular momentum from the lattice to the spin system owing to the combined action of SO and exchange coupling." is given which seems pretty clear, as it's purely quantum mechanical I don't think there's a more "intuitive" explanation

Comment: I hadn't heard of spin-orbit torque, but spin-orbit coupling (such as Rashba spin-orbit coupling) couples an electron's spin to its orbital angular momentum. This is a relativistic effect from an effective electric field felt by the electrons in the material.

Answer (score 1):

The spin-orbit torque is defined as when the movement of rotational momentum can affect magnetic moments alignment within that material. When electricity flows through some materials, it sorts electrons based on their spin directions and this creates a state called [spin Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_Hall_effect). Consequently, this spatial flow of spins can push the magnetization orientation in materials like ferromagnet. Generally referred to as “spin-orbit torque”, this force is distinct from spin-transfer torque that occurs from electron-magnetic layer exchange of their angular momenta. Basically, Spin-orbit torque possessively acts like a magnetic field which causes magnetization in ferromagnet towards being oriented in specific ways for instance along the external fields applied or easy-axes. Still, there is ongoing debate about the details of how spin-orbit torque arises with some primarily linking it to the spin Hall effect while others suggest additional contributions such as [Rashba effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashba_effect). For a comprehensive analysis of magnetisation dynamics, [Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert (LLG) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation) plays a great role and thus adding component due to spin-orbit torque affects how magnetisation changes over time. Generally speaking, the impact of introducing spin-orbit torque is very important because it opens up new possibilities for for managing magnetic devices.